# design documents for ros2_control transmissions

Tags: ros2-control, transmission

Does anybody know where I can find architecture design documents for ros2_control transmissions?

I'm interested to know:

- Why `ReadOnlyHandle` uses a pointer to double, `value_ptr_`, to hold a value?
- Why `joint_to_actuator()` and `actuator_to_joint()` have to use implicit internal variables instead of taking inputs and return outputs?

To me, cognitive load of the current implmentation is very high.  To my mental model, a transmission is simply a function which takes a few inputs and return a few inputs.  Why can't they be something along the line of:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <pair>

class Transmission {
};

class SimpleTransmission : public Transmission {
public:
    double actuator_to_joint(double a1) const {
        return a1 * 2;
    }
};

class DifferentialTransmission : public Transmission {
public:
    std::pair<double, double> actuator_to_joint(double a1, double a2) const {
        return std::make_pair(a1 * 2, a2 * 2);
    }
};

int main() {
    SimpleTransmission simple;
    DifferentialTransmission diff;

    auto joint = simple.actuator_to_joint(3.14);
    auto joints = diff.actuator_to_joint(1.1, 2.2);

    std::cout << "Simple: " << joint << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Differential: " << joints.first << ", " << joints.second << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the design drafts in [this repository](https://github.com/ros-controls/roadmap/tree/master/design_drafts), but not sure if you find answers to your questions. If not, feel free to post a question in the [ros2_control issues](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues).

Comment: https://github.com/ros-controls/roadmap/blob/master/design_drafts/joint_interfaces_and_transmissions.md#transmissions Thanks for the pointer.  It does state that "The Transmission interface and base class should be merged and simplified. There is little benefit in providing multitudes of classes, requiring multitudes of checks all following the same pattern. I am proposing a much simpler setup as outlined below."  But it doesn't explain the current implementation.  But I'm glad @BenceMagyar seems to think that Transmission interface should be simplified.

Comment: There aren't a lot of users of the transmissions, that's why it didn't get that much attention yet. If you can contribute, we are happy to discuss and [review your PRs](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/contributing/contributing.html).

Comment: done. https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control/issues/1305